# Как правильно употребить слово "понятия"?

Tags: управление, род, падежи

Ничто так не путает понятий об искусстве, как признание авторитетов. Почему "понятий", а не "понятия"?

Comment: Ничто так не вредит пониманию искусства, как почитание авторитетов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ничто так не путает понятий (Р.п.) об искусстве, как признание авторитетов.**

При переходных глаголах **с отрицанием** может использоваться Р.п. или В.п.

**Р.п.** ―  подчеркнутое (классическое) отрицание, книжная речь, **В.п**. ― ослабленное отрицание, разговорная речь.

Кроме того, на выбор падежа могут влиять **различные факторы,** в данном случае это **усиление отрицания** с помощью местоименного наречия "ничто".

Comment: http://tepka.ru/rozental_2/201.html Это Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке Розенталя Д.Э., откуда и взят материал. Р.п. используется при наличии в предложении частицы ни или начинающихся с частицы ни местоимения или наречия, например: Да мы не имеем ни малейшего понятия о том, что делается с этими несчастными... (Л. Толстой); Никогда еще он не ощущал так горестно своей беззащитности, бессилия своего (Горький); До вас никто еще этого браслета не надевал (Куприн); ...Нисколько не облегчает процесса чтения (акад. Ф.Ф. Фортунатов);

Answer (score 0):

Здесь употребление родительного не оправдано.

Родительный при отрицании используется обычно с некоторыми наиболее частыми глаголами (иметь, ждать, писать и проч.), имеющими ярко выраженную переходность. Путать к ним не относится.

Правил на этот счет вы вряд ли найдете, только статистическую и стилистическую закономерность. *Не путай берега/детали/случаи* и *не путай берегов/деталей/случаев*. Вряд ли кто скажет, что второе звучит лучше. Думаю, что статистика это подтвердит. Причем даже контекст трудно найти подходящий для оправдания второго варианта.

Так что я бы отнес *"не путает понятий"* к стилистической небрежности.